# unordered_set & unordered_map

Tags: c++, stl

Правильно ли я понял, что unordered_set хранит хэш для значений, а unordered_map хранит хэш для ключей?

Мало информации, всё как-то завуалированно. Поэтому хотелось бы получить ответ непосредственно от тех людей, которые разбираются в вопросе.

Comment: В случае `set` **нет значений** - есть только ключи. Или, говоря иначе, значения и есть ключи.

Comment: @Harry, и я об этом же.

Comment: @Πανμέτρονάριστον вроде обычно говорят unordered_set - неупорядоченное множество уникальных элементов, а inorderes_map просто хэш таблица